# How to establish communication between Angular 9 container and ASP.NET Core 3.1 container using container names instead of static IP?

Tags: angular, docker, asp.net-core, docker-network

So I have 2 containers running on my local machine. I would like them to communicate internally through the networking of docker itself and not have to go through the host.

for example: I would like to make a call to an API from the angular container to the backend container and I want to achieve something like this in the url that I am writing inside my angular code

"backend-container-name/api/resource" instead of "http://natIP:port/api/resource"

Comment: If one part is an Angular application, that runs in your browser, not inside Docker (even if the content is served out of a Docker container) and so you can't use any of the Docker-related networking features.

Comment: @DavidMaze So, in your opinion Anuraj's answer won't work either? I haven't really used compose before

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Docker compose to provision the containers, you can use the service names as the container names and communicate.

Here is an example of docker compose file.

version: "3"

```
services:
    web:
        build: .
        ports:
            - "8000:80"
        depends_on:
            - db
    db:
        image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server"
        environment:
            SA_PASSWORD: "Your_password123"
            ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
```

And you can refer the SQL Server name as db in the connection string. Similarly you can create an API server and use the service name.

Comment: I would assume that this should also be done without relying on docker compose. If so, what would be the alternative to this?